# Pvalue formula for table1 not working with t test: grouping factor must have exactly two levels

Tags: r

I am trying to include a P value column in table1, which I have done a couple of times before and had no problem. In this case, I get this error message: Error in t.test.formula(y ~ g) :
grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels.

Here is a reproducible example of the problem:

```
install.packages("table1")

library(table1)

set.seed(42)

lpa_mean <- 58.2
lpa_std <- 10.7
group_values <- factor(c(rep("No", 57), rep("Sí", 45)))

lpa <- rnorm(102, lpa_mean, lpa_std)
group <- sample(group_values, 102, replace = TRUE)

df <- data.frame(lpa, group)

pvalue <- function(x, ...) {
  # Construct vectors of data y, and groups (strata) g
  y <- unlist(x)
  g <- factor(rep(1:length(x), times=sapply(x, length)))
  if (is.numeric(y)) {
    # For numeric variables, perform a standard 2-sample t-test
    p <- t.test(y ~ g)$p.value
  } else {
    # For categorical variables, perform a chi-squared test of independence
    p <- fisher.test(table(y ~ g))$p.value
  }
  # Format the p-value, using an HTML entity for the less-than sign.
  # The initial empty string places the output on the line below the variable label.
  c("", sub("<", "&lt;", format.pval(p, digits=3, eps=0.001)))
}

table1(~ lpa| group, data=df, extra.col=list(`P-value`=pvalue))
```

I made sure that my grouping variable is a factor with two levels, so I can't really find the way to solve this.

I also tried to change the ~ for a , in the p value formula for the t.test, and then I get a different error:

> Error in var(y) : Calling var(x) on a factor x is defunct.
> Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector.
> In addition: Warning message:
> In mean.default(y) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Comment: Not reproducible.  What package does `table1` come from?  `pvalue(df)` gives potentially sensible results, so the problem would appear to be with the manner in which you are passing the function to `table1`.  Welcome to SO.